# How to execute mvn clean install in goCD

Tags: go-cd

mvn clean build command does not execute in GoCD , The pipe line gets triggered  but there is nothing displayed in logs and the job keeps running forever after setting inactivity time to 1 min.

[image: task logs]

I have created a pipe line and added mvn clean install command to it as in below image.Please let me know what needs to changed to generate artifacts as first step.

[image: task configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important clue is in your first screenshot, it says "Agent: Not yet assigned". That means that no agent (aka worker) could be found that that can handle your job.

Please read the [manual on managing agents](https://docs.gocd.org/current/configuration/managing_a_build_cloud.html), specifically the section **Matching jobs to agents**.

Frequent reasons why no agent can be assigned:

- No agents available at all
- The agent(s) are in environments, but the pipeline isn't
- Mismatch between resources specified in the job and in the agent management.